# How to automatically enable Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I installed [Bundler & Minifier](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40) extension on Visual Studio Community 2015. Every time i open a project, this extension is disabled. I have to enable it and restart VS to get it work.

[image]

How can i automatically enable this Visual Studio extension ?

Thanks.

Comment: VS extensions are enabled by default, unless explicitly disabled. When you open VS with no solution loaded, is the extension enabled? And then is disabled if you load a project? Does it happen the same with another user account on your computer? Or on another computer?

Comment: It's disabled if i open VS with no solution and also if i directly open a project. If i open one of my project on another computer, it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up by :

1. Uninstall *Bundler & Minifier* extension
2. Restart my computer
3. Then reinstall the extension

Now everything works fine.